# How to record inputs and play them back for a demo?

Tags: unity, input, game-recording

I was curious how I can implement a good system for recording inputs to make Quake/Doom style demos in Unity.

I'm relatively new to game dev so figured I'd ask some people with actual experience.

Comment: [Unity's new Input System package now comes with an `InputRecorder` class](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.1/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputRecorder.html) specifically for supporting recording/playback use cases. Have you tried working with that, or searching for existing tutorials/guides/example projects that use it?